Second Derivative test for Euler Lagrange.
Recall the Euler-Lagrange equation, stated below for convenience. How can I justify a solution to this equation is a minimum? Is there an analog of the second derivative test in this setting?
${\bf Statement}$
Let $J$ be the functional defined by $$J[f] := \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}L(t,f(t),f'(t))$$ with an extremum on the interval $[t_1,t_2]$. Let $x(t)$ be a $C^1[t_1,t_2]$ function that extremizes $J$. Then the following equation must be satified:
$$
        \frac{d}{dt} \cdot \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}.
$$

See Second variation and sufficient conditions for a minimum

In the same spirit as usual optimization, compute the second functional derivative of $J$ and evaluate the latter at the solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation, in order to see whether the result is positive, negative or zero.

Specifically, it must be positive definite

To be correct, the variational principle states, that the solution have zero first variational differential in the 'set' of all paths in fixed time passing two points $x(t_1)=x_1, \ x(t_2)=x_2.$
$$ \delta \left(\frac{1}{t_2-t_1} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathit L(t,f(t),f'(t)) \ dt\right) =   (\delta f)(t)\ \left(  \frac{1}{t_2-t_1} \ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left( \partial_t + \partial_f  - \frac{d}{dt}\partial_{f'} \right) \  L(t,f(t),f'(t)) \right)\ dt \  + \  o\left((\delta f(t))^2\right)$$
In simple words: for a free particle, the time mean of the kinetic energy is stationary. It does not change linearly with any samll accelaration manoeuvers or deviations for a shot  from earth to Jupiter in a given time.
The potential term $\partial_f$ says, you can save mean energy by navigating along paths of low potential energy, that supplies kinetic energy at no cost. So stationary paths favorably follow the valleys even if the pass is shorter.
In the limit of short time and short distance one has the case of high kinetic energy. The potential term becomes negligible: The path is the geodesic shortest distance travelled at constant arc length velocity.
That we can speak in physics about straight lines is due to light rays. They travel at the highest possible velocity and as such are the foundation of euclidean geometry in the small scale.
Genarally, the set of global long time  solutions forms a saddle point, but thats a difficult toöological area.
Consider e.g the paths of all Kepler ellipses of the same greater axis and  passing a common $x_1=x_2$ point after the same period $T=t_2-t_1$

This doesn’t really answer OP’s question. The direct analogue of the second derivative test exists in variations calculus and is determined by ensuring that the second variation is positive definite  in every feasible direction.
